# Compile Liquid in Sass to Css ( Gulp + Scss + Shopify )

Tags: sass, gulp, shopify, liquid

I'm wondering if there is a workaround to :

- Use Liquid in `.scss` files
- Then compile all `.scss` files to `.css`

Right now, i'm using a custom theme starter that's using gulp to compile my `.scss` files to a unique `theme.css` file. I'd like to use liquid in my `.scss` files and then still compile all of this to `.css`.

For now, i can't add `.scss.liquid` to my files because if i do that, then the compiler freaks out as it obviously doesn't recognize `.liquid` extensions. I've found [an article](https://adambohannon.me/shopify-development-using-liquid-syntax-in-sass-and-compiling-with-gulp) talking about how to compile files to `.scss.liquid` but that's not what i want since Shopify won't use Scss in the future. I'd like to compile directly to `.css`.

Here is what my current task looks like for my sass files :

```
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');

sass.compiler = require('node-sass')

const styles = () => src('src/styles/theme.scss')
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(rename('theme.css'))
  .pipe(dest('dist/assets/'));

module.exports = styles;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an article that covers this issue here:
https://ablesense.com/blogs/news/using-gulp-to-compile-sass-liquid-tags

Effectively the solution to compiling liquid tags in SASS is to use the native feature in SASS that allows you to escape out strings `#{' your escaped {{ liquid tags }} here '}` which will allow linting & transpiling to CSS and then using PostCSS to reformat the output into clean liquid tags.

An arguably better option is to skip the issue entirely and use CSS variables in your SASS while adding your liquid variables into `:root` in the `<head>` of the layout.liquid

Your SASS:

```css
btn.primary {
    background-color: var(--color-btn-primary);
}
```

In the `<head>` of your liquid.layout:

```
{% style %}
  :root {
    --color-btn-primary: {{ settings.color_button }}
  }
{% endstyle %}
```

This is covered in detail here:
https://www.shopify.com.au/partners/blog/deprecating-sass

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already read this article, the main issue is that it compiles to .scss.liquid and not to .css. But i've figured out it would be easier to create a css-variables.liquid file, import it in my theme.liquid and in my sass use the css variables as values for my variables (eg. $color-text: var(--color-text)